# Issues with Dependency Libraries in Eclipse Using Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I a newbie in Gradle and trying to find my way around it but facing some issues that needs to be resolved before i can proceed my Gradle tutorials.

At the moment i have compiled the app from the command prompt and seems to be working.

The issues i have now is that i can't see the dependencies (spring libraries) that Gradle has downloaded in Eclipse. If i look into the `"Project and External Dependencies"` folder in eclipse under the Gradle project i have created, i can't see the spring libraries there. For instance in Maven, the moment you add a dependency and save the POM file, the dependencies are added to the library instantly. Because of this issue red-error-markers appear in the source codes that are using the spring libraries though the application runs perfect from the command line.

How do i fix this problem? Does Gradle put the libraries somewhere?

My buld.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = System.getProperty("mainClass")

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.14'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.5.RELEASE'
}
```

thanks.

**Extra question ::** is there a way to let Gradle run in eclipse so that the output of my application is displayed in the eclipse console?

Comment: how do you import your project into eclipse? I recommend to use the buildship plugin and its import functionality. That allows you to execute the `run` task from the eclipse UI with having the output on the eclipse console.

Comment: @ReneGroeschke I don't import any project into eclipse. I just use the  "New->Other->Gradle->Gradle Project" to create a new project. Do i have to import a project?